# What is the correct way to say "to ask a question"?

Tags: word-choice

I have said ***demandi demandon*** before and no one has ever corrected me. However, it always sounds awkward to me to have these two words together and I always wonder if people think I sound like an idiot saying it this way.

Well, I just read ***starigi demandon***. Is this a better way to say it? If not, what is the correct way?

Is "demandi demandon" even correct at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Demandi demandon* to me means "to ask a question something." One way to say "to ask a question" is simply *demandi*. What else are you going to ask other than a question?

The verb I have always used with "demandon" as the object is *starigi*. I was not familiar with *fari demandon* (although in 20 years, I must have heard it multiple times.) My impression from looking through modern texts in tekstaro.com (e.g. *artikoloj de monato*)is that "starigi demandon" is at least slightly more common if not clearly so. (11 variations of *fari demandon* and 13 variations of *starigi demandon* using the same search methods.)

I'm sure all three are fine.

Answer (score 12):

Usually, the object of the verb *demandi* is the person being asked, e.g. *Li demandis min pri la historio de la loko*.

In [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/), if you search "demandon", you will find several examples of *fari demandon* meaning "to ask a question". E.g. *permesu, ke mi faru demandon*. This is slightly different than *starigi demandon* which means "to pose a question".

Comment: *starigi demandon* is also common in Tekstaro.

Answer (score 9):

*Demandi demandon* is grammatically correct, but I understand the desire to avoid redundancy of the same root being repeated.  One option is to rephrase it slightly.  Instead you can "ask something": *demandi ion*.

Comment: Given that *demandi* is defined in PIV as *Peti pri sciigo, informo*, I would agree that *demandi demandon* is grammatically correct, but not semantically correct, since it would have to mean *Peti demandon pri sciigo, informo* or *sciigi al demando, ke oni deziras ricevi informojn de ĝi*.

Answer (score 4):

According to the PIV, one can *fari demandon*, *meti demandon*, *direkti demandon (al iu)*; all these usages are from the works of Zamenhof. *Fari demandon* seems the closest to generic English 'ask a question'; the other two I would translate as 'put a question' and 'direct a question (to someone)'. I would say that *demandi demandon* is probably to be avoided.

BTW, the PIV (Plena Ilustrita Vortaro) is accessible online at http://vortaro.net. It's a wonderfully useful resource and now thanks to the interwebs quite easy to consult without hauling out a heavy and expensive book.

Answer (score 2):

`Ĉu mi povas demandi pri io?` in some cases will do too. Other languages will often use such a form.

`Ĉu mi povas fari demandon?` in other languages use a help verb `stellen` (de, nl), `poser` (fr).

The English form with its semantic redundancy is an exception.