# La objekto de "demandi"

Tags: questions

"Demandi" estas transitiva verbo. Do, oni devas demandi ion (aŭ "pri io"? Vidu poste). Nu, kion oni devas uzi kiel objekton kun "demandi"? Ĉu tio pri kio oni demandas ("Mi demandas scii la veron") aŭ tiu al kiu ni faras la demandon ("Mi demandas vin [pri la monujo]")? Ĉu ambaŭ estas ĝustaj? Ĉu mi devas skribi "Al kiu vi demandas la informon" aŭ "Kiun vi demandas pri la informon"?

Ĉu estas ĝenerala regulo por similaj verboj?

Ĝisdatigo: estas [alia demando](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/869) kiu demandis pri "demandi" (tiom multe da "demandoj" en la sama frazo :P ). Tamen, ĝi ne pritraktas la saman dubon. En tiu demando, oni lernas precipe pri kiel diri la esprimo "to ask a question", ne pri la ĝenerala uzado de la verbo "demandi". Do, ĝi estas rilata sed ne respondas tion pri kio mi demandis. Unu el respondoj tie tuŝas tion pri kio mi scivolemas, sed la respondoj ĉi tie estas tre pli kompletaj kaj bonaj.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to say "to ask a question"?](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-is-the-correct-way-to-say-to-ask-a-question)

Comment: "Mi demandas scii la veron" sxajnas al mi malgxusta. La vorto "demandi" ne havas la signifon de la angla "demand", nek de la angla "request, ask for".

Comment: Mi nepre ne pensas ke cxi tiu demando estas sama kiel la alia. Mi mem pensis pri la objekto de "demandi".

Comment: @kristan Mi konsentas. La sola objekto de tiu kategorio estas "demandon". Por klarigi kion mi pensas ke domiriel celas: Cxu oni demandas 1. iun pri io 2. ion al iu 3. pri io al iu?

Comment: Here is the same question concerning a different verb.  (instrui) http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/what-is-the-object-of-instrui

Answer (score 5):

La objekto estas la demandato - tio estas la persono, kiun vi demandas.

Vidu

[What is the correct way to say "to ask a question"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-is-the-correct-way-to-say-to-ask-a-question)

Oni ankaŭ vidas esprimojn kiel **demandi ion** aŭ **demandi tion**, sed plej ofte la formo estas: **demandi iun pri io**.

Comment: Memorigas min pri la tikla sintakso de 'provizi'.

Answer (score 4):

> Ĉu mi devas skribi "Al kiu vi demandas la informon" aŭ "Kiun vi demandas pri la informon"?

La dua frazo enhavas erareton: Devus esti "pri la informo" anstataŭ "pri la informon" (neniam estas akuzativo post "pri"). Se oni tiel korektas la duan frazon, ambaŭ frazoj estas ĝustaj, sed la dua frazo sekvas multe pli kutiman skemon ol la unua frazo. Alivorte, plej ofte la objekto de la demando estas la persono, al kiu oni direktas la demandon, kaj la temo de la demando estas esprimata per "pri". Sed ankaŭ eblas mencii la temon kiel objekton, kaj tiam eblas mencii la demandatan personon per "al".

> Ĉu estas ĝenerala regulo por similaj verboj?

Ĝenerale oni devas lerni kune kun la signifo de verbo ankaŭ la rolojn, kiujn ludas la subjekto kaj la objekto en la ago esprimita per la verbo. Alivorte, ne ekzistas meĥanika regulo aplikebla al ĉiuj verboj.

Ekzemple, "respondi" havas signifon iel analogan al "demandi", en la senco, ke ankaŭ ĉe respondado ekzistas iu persono, kiu faras la agon, alia persono, al kiu la ago estas direktata, kaj iu temo/diraĵo. Tamen ĉe "respondi", la objekto ĉiam estas la temo/diraĵo, kaj la persono, al kiu la respondo estas direktata, povas esti menciata nur per uzo de "al". Do "respondi" ĉiam funkcias laŭ la skemo, kiu ĉe "demandi" estas tre malofta.

Malsame ol en la angla, en Esperanto la rolo de la subjekto en la ago esprimita de verbo estas ĉiam fiksita surbaze de la signifo de la verbo. En la angla estas multaj verboj, kiel "to move", "to change", "to start" kaj "to boil", ĉe kiuj la subjekto povas ludi du malsamajn rolojn rilate al la ago esprimita de la verbo. Pro tio anglalingvanoj ofte havas malfacilaĵon lerni, ke Esperanto uzas du malsamajn verbojn depende de tio, kiun rolon havas la subjekto en la ago. Tiu malfacilaĵo ofte estas klarigata per tio, ke oni devas lerni, kiuj Esperantaj verboj estas transitivaj kaj kiuj estas netransitivaj. Sed tiu klarigo ne estas tre bona, ĉar la centra demando ĉe tiaj verboj ne estas, ĉu la verbo povas havi objekton, sed kiun signifon havas la subjekto.

Ĉe multaj verboj ankaŭ la rolo de la objekto estas klare fiksita (kiel ĉe "respondi"), dum ĉe multaj aliaj verboj (kiel ĉe "demandi") la rolo de la objekto estas fleksebla (eĉ se, kiel ĉe "demandi", plej ofte ekzistas unu rolo, kiu plej ofte estas esprimata per la objekto). Aliaj ekzemploj de verboj, ĉe kiuj la objekto povas esprimi diversajn rolojn estas "pagi" (ĉe kiu la objekto povas esti la prezo, la aĉetaĵo, la pagilo aŭ la ricevanto de la pago), "peti", "danki", "pardoni", kaj ĉiuj verboj formitaj per aldono de "-ig-" al transitiva verbo (ekzemple "sciigi" kaj "manĝigi"). Vidu la [klarigojn de PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/alternativoj.html#i-673) pri ĉi tiu temo. Do iusence la situacio pri la objektoj en Esperanto estas simila al la situacio pri la subjektoj en la angla (ja ĉe multaj anglaj verboj, la rolo de la subjekto estas fiksita, dum ĉe multaj aliaj, ĝi ne estas fiksita).

Eĉ ĉe la verboj, ĉe kiuj estas pli ol unu eblo por la rolo de la objekto, oni devas lerni kiel parton de la signifo de la verbo, kiuj roloj estas esprimeblaj per la objekto. Aldone estas utile lerni, kiu rolo estas plej ofte esprimata per la objekto (por ke oni ĝenerale uzu la pli kutiman skemon, kaj uzu la malpli kutiman nur, kiam tio ial aparte utilas).

Konklude, oni bone lernu la signifojn de verboj, inkluzive de la rolo, kiun la subjekto havas en la ago esprimita de la verbo, kaj inkluzive de la rolo(j), kiu(j)n la objekto povas havi en  tiu ago. Se oni tiel bone lernas la signfojn de verboj, ne plu estas duboj. Se oni nur enmemorigas, kiun agon esprimas la verbo, sen enmemorigi la rolojn de la subjekto kaj objekto, oni daŭre havos dubojn, ĉar ne ekzistas ĝenerala regulo por determini la rolojn de la subjekto kaj objekto el la nuda ago.

Answer (score 1):

Mi demandis la hundon, sed la hundo ne sciis. Mi demandis [onin] pri la hundo, sed oni ne sciis.

---

> Mi demandas [onin / iun / homon / lin / ŝin] scii la veron

Ĝusta

> Mi demandas vin

Ĝusta

> Al kiu vi demandas la informon

Ĝusta

> Kiun vi demandas pri la informon

malĝusta - Kiun vi demandas pri la informo

---

El la tekstaro - Objekto estas homo, kiu vi parolus kun:

> - ...kaj demandas **al ŝi** nur ion supraĵan
> - ...oni demandas **al mi** ridante...
> - ...mi demandis **lin** pri la vojo...
> - Kiam oni demandas **min** pri mia lingvo...

El la tekstaro - Informo, kiu vi volas scii:

> - Kiam li demandis **pri novaĵoj**
> - Mi ne demandas **tion**...
> - Ramzes demandis **pri la kaŭzo**
> - ...kaj demandis **pri ordonoj**

Comment: En via lasta ekzemplo: *„Kiun vi demandas pri la informon“* — havas du akuzativajn finaĵojn, ĉu? Kaj poste vi skribis: *„Kiu vi demandis pri la informo“* — ne havas objekton, ĉu? Kiu el la du do estas malĝusta? Ĉu ambaŭ? Mi ne komprenas…

Comment: @Lumo5 - mi dubas pri kelkaj el viaj ekzemploj. "Al kiu vi demandas la informon?" Cxu tio estas elpensita ekzemplo? Tio devus esti "de kiu vi petas la informojn." Mi trovis nur unu similan ekzemplon en la Tekstaro (la frazeron "[Mi] demandis kelkajn informojn") kaj tio versxajne estas ekzemplo de la "evitinda" uzo de la rimarko en PIV. Gxi devus esti "Mi **petis** kelkajn informojn. ***Due*** "pri novaĵoj", "pri la kaŭzo" kaj "pri ordonoj" ne estas objektoj. Krome, mi konsilas diri "**mi ne demandas pri tio**" kaj ne "mi ne demandas tion."

Comment: Mi redaktis mian respondon. Dankon.